# Prove that there do not exist integers that satisfy the system

Tags: number-theory, systems-of-equations, diophantine-equations

> Prove that there do not exist integers $x,y,z,w,t,$ that satisfy \begin{align*}(x+1)^2+y^2 &= (x+2)^2+z^2\\(x+2)^2+z^2 &= (x+3)^2+w^2\\(x+3)^2+w^2 &= (x+4)^2+t^2.\end{align*}

I thought about using a modular arithmetic argument. The given system is equivalent to \begin{align*}y^2 &= 2x+3+z^2\\z^2 &= 2x+5+w^2\\w^2 &= 2x+7+t^2.\end{align*} Thus $y^2 = 6x+15+t^2$. How can we find a contradiction from this?

Comment: Sometimes with problems involving squares, you can get a more additively flavored proof by using the fact that differences between squares are sums of consecutive odd numbers. Your second system is a statement about four squares of increasing size, and the size of the gaps between them. Maybe something can be done with that.

Answer (score 5):

Let's look at the equations modulo $8$. Notice that the only squares modulo $8$ are $0,1$ and $4$.

### Case $(1)$: $x \equiv 0,4 \pmod 8$

Then we have the system

\begin{align*}
y^2&\equiv z^2+3\\
z^2&\equiv w^2+5\\
w^2 &\equiv t^2+7\end{align*}

The first equation implies $y^2\equiv 4$ and $z^2\equiv 1$. This implies $w^2 \equiv 4$ via the second equation. But then the third equation implies becomes $t^2 \equiv 5$, which cannot be.

### Case $(2)$: $x \equiv 2,6 \pmod 8$

Then we have the system

\begin{align*}
y^2&\equiv z^2+7\\
z^2&\equiv w^2+1\\\
w^2 &\equiv t^2+3\end{align*}

The first equation implies $y^2\equiv 0$ and $z^2\equiv 1$. This implies $w^2 \equiv 0$ via the second equation. But then the third equation implies becomes $t^2 \equiv 5$, which cannot be.

### Case $(3)$: $x \equiv 1,5 \pmod 8$

Then we have the system

\begin{align*}
y^2&\equiv z^2+5\\
z^2&\equiv w^2-1\\
w^2 &\equiv t^2+1\end{align*}

The first equation implies $y^2\equiv 1$ and $z^2 \equiv 4$, but then the second equation cannot be satisfied.

### Case $(4)$: $x \equiv 3,7 \pmod 8$

Then we have the system

\begin{align*}
y^2&\equiv z^2+1\\
z^2&\equiv w^2+3\\
w^2 &\equiv t^2+5\end{align*}

The first equation implies $y^2\equiv 1$ and $z^2\equiv 0$, but then the second cannot be satisfied, and this concludes our proof.

Comment: Your case 1 is incorrect since $z^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{4}$, not $0$.

Comment: You are right, I will try and correct it.

Comment: @Puzzled417 I have fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

My solution is similar, in spirit, to Fimpellizieri's, but organized a little differently ...

Suppose $x,y,z,w,t$ are integers such that

\begin{align}
2x + 3 &= y^2 - z^2 \tag{eq1}\\
2x + 5 &= z^2 - w^2 \tag{eq2}\\
2x + 7 &= w^2 - t^2 \tag{eq3}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
\text{Equation } (1)  &\implies y,z \text{ have opposite parity.}\\
\text{Equation } (2)  &\implies z,w \text{ have opposite parity.}\\
\text{Equation } (3)  &\implies w,t \text{ have opposite parity.}
\end{align}

Thus one of the following cases must hold:

- $y,w$ are odd, and $z,t$ are even.

  $y,w$ are even, and $z,t$ are odd.

Consider each case separately.

The key is that an even square must be a multiple of 4, and an odd square must be congruent to 1 (mod 8).

First suppose $y,w$ are odd, and $z,t$ are even.

Then $(\text{eq}2) -(\text{eq}1)$ yields:

\begin{align}
&2z^2 - y^2 - w^2 = 2\\
\implies &2z^2 - y^2 - w^2 \equiv 2 \text{ }(\text{mod }8)\\
\implies &{-2} \equiv 2 \text{ }(\text{mod }8)
\end{align}

contradiction.

Next suppose $y,w$ are even, and $z,t$ are odd.

Then $(\text{eq}3) -(\text{eq}2)$ yields:

\begin{align}
&2w^2 - z^2 - t^2 = 2\\
\implies &2w^2 - z^2 - t^2 \equiv 2 \text{ }(\text{mod }8)\\
\implies &{-2} \equiv 2 \text{ }(\text{mod }8)
\end{align}

contradiction.

It follows that the given system of equations has no integer solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This can easily be equated to an extension of [the pattern I found for your similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2085639/276406).

Specifically, **any sequence of consecutive odd integers which can be partitioned into three groups such that the sum of the group of smaller numbers is an odd number $2$ greater than the sum of the group of middle numbers, which is in turn $2$ greater than the sum of the group of larger numbers,** can be used to derive a solution to this system of equations.

Likewise, any solution to your system of equations can be used to derive such a sequence of consecutive odd integers; the two problems are in fact equivalent.

---

Given the proofs provided in other answers that the original system of equations is impossible, we now know that it is *also* impossible to describe a sequence of positive odd integers which can be divided into three partitions as described above.

(I'd be interested in a direct proof of that fact, but don't have time at the moment to puzzle one out.)

Answer (score 0):

You are asking about four $x$ values. These are consecutive, so they assume the four values $0,1,2,3 \pmod 4.$ Let us give them new names,
$$ x_1 \equiv 1 \pmod 4, \; \;  x_2 \equiv 2 \pmod 4, \; \;  x_3 \equiv 3 \pmod 4, \; \;  x_4 \equiv 0 \pmod 4.  $$

$$ n = x_1^2 + y_1^2 =  x_2^2 + y_2^2 = x_3^2 + y_3^2 = x_4^2 + y_4^2 $$

First we prove that $n$ is odd. Assume $n$ is even.
 $x_1^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 8.$ If $y_1$ is odd, then $n \equiv 2 \pmod 8$ is not divisible by $4.$ However, $x_4^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 8.$ With $y_4$ even, we get $n$ divisible by $4.$ The impossibility about $n$ being divisible by 4 and not divisible by 4  contradicts the assumption that $n$ was even. So, actually, $n$ is odd.

Again, $x_4^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 8.$ With the necessary odd $y_4,$ we have $y_4^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 8,$ so
$$ n \equiv 1 \pmod 8.  $$

However, $x_2^2 \equiv 4 \pmod 8.$ With the necessary odd $y_2,$ we have $y_2^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 8,$ so
$$ n \equiv 5 \pmod 8.  $$

The inconsistent values $1,5 \pmod 8$ contradict the assumption that there were four  $ x_1 \equiv 1 \pmod 4, \; \;  x_2 \equiv 2 \pmod 4, \; \;  x_3 \equiv 3 \pmod 4, \; \;  x_4 \equiv 0 \pmod 4.  $

In turn, this contradicts the assumption that we can take the $x$ values $x+1, x+2, x+3, x+4.$